# pymssql get SQL command - last_executed

Tags: python, insert, pymssql

I have a python script what isnert data to a MS SQL databse. Part of my code:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (a,b,c))
```

The a, b and c are variables.
I want to print executed SQL command. Is this possible?

My goal is log/print every executed SQL command e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES ('Lemon','Apple','Orange')
```

Like a _last_executed attribute on pymysql cursor.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
print ("INSERT INTO TABLE (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (a,b,c))
```

Comment: Good idea, but not exactly what I meant. I'm curious to code which actually ran longer e.g. _last_executed_ property

Comment: @cofeee - Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39773253/edit) to better explain what you really want to achieve. Do you want to see the effective SQL statement after parameter substitution, or do you want to see the time it took to perform the most recent query?